# Dynamic analysis of cmd dependent software

Tags: binary-analysis, windbg, x86-64

There is a PE file, which can't run by itself, and can only be called from `cmd.exe`, it doesn't create independent processes, and can be launched independently only with `.bat` scripts, which without "pause" just execute themselves and self-destruct. Trying to attach debugger to cmd, only debugs the `cmd.exe` process. So am I doing something very wrong, or there is no real way to dynamically analyze this PE file?

Comment: You forgot to include the command that is required to call that PE files from cmd. That would allow us to better understand what you are talking about.

Comment: My bad. First you need to drop down into folder with our program.exe, and then just call it by name, so it's like 
`cd C:/Users/User/Programs/Program1
program.exe arg1 arg2`

Comment: Then you just execute the PE file and get a separate process. May be the process only exists for some milliseconds and then injects itself in a different process? Using Sysinternals ProcessMonitor I am sure you will see that there is a process and how long it lives.